# Delete selected gridview row

Tags: asp.net, gridview

trying to delete selected gridview row. I read few sites and used code however I am getting error. I think because most of the codes I've seen they using DataGridView, This code is within delete button event

```
   For i = 0 To myGridView.Rows.Count - 1 Step i + 1
        Dim delrow As GridViewRow = myGridView.Rows(i)
        If delrow.Selected = True Then
            myGridView.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
```

the two errors I am getting are:

1) RemoveAt is not a member of GridViewRowCollection
2) Selected is not a member of GridViewRow

Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Delete the source data item and rebind the Gridview.

Comment: VDWWD, how can you choose the datasource.. myGridView.DataSource??

Comment: What are you binding to the GridView. Let's say it it a Database table. If you want to remove a row from the gridview you have to make sure that it is removed from the database or does not show up in the selection anymore and then rebind the girdview.

Comment: Thanks :D - I got the idea I will try it and let u know if I manage to remove data. I just don't understand who down voted my question, I think it is very valid question not some simple stuff!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually delete rows on GridViews putting an ImageButton (with a trash bin) on every row with a Template Field, then on RowDataBound event I associate "DeleteRow" event and rowIndex to the CommandName and CommandArgument

```
Protected Sub myGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim ib As ImageButton = e.Row.FindControl("ibDeleteRow")
        ib.CommandName = "DeleteRow"
        ib.CommandArgument = e.Row.RowIndex
    End if
end sub

Private Sub myGridView_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowCommand
    If e.CommandName = "DeleteRow" Then
        Dim rowToDeleteIndex as integer = e.CommandArgument
        myGridView.DeleteRow(rowToDeleteIndex)
    end if
end sub

Private Sub myGridView_RowDeleting(sender As Object, e As GridViewDeleteEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDeleting

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, I tried your solution but I got this error:  Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: It seems that you don't have any selected rows, so myGridView.SelectedIndex = -1. Are you using this code in RowCommand event ?

Comment: No, I created my own button click method, I created button called it delete then generated its method. let me generate on RowCommand method and try it

Comment: how can I create a button and attach it to RowCommand method??

Comment: Sorry didnt see your updated answer. I will go through it now and inform you! Cheers:)

Comment: Your way didn't work for me, I created onCommand and onRowDeleting method. The first is returning the selected row index but the onRowDeleting which should handles the deleting is throwing error

Comment: @Sam notice that I did not use the standard "Delete" CommandName, instead "DeleteRow" is a custom CommandName that is dealt with in RowCommand event (not in RowDeleting event). You should stick with my example and it should work.

Comment: Protected Sub myGridView_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
        Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(((CType(e.CommandSource, Button)).NamingContainer), GridViewRow)
        Dim index As Integer = row.RowIndex
      myGridView.DeleteRow(index) // when reached this line it says error onRowDeleting method was fired but not handled
    End Sub

Comment: How can I format the code in the comment, at least now index is returning the correct index number so just getting it delete it. will inspect your code again

Comment: With the ` character (see help link on the right-hand side)

Comment: Ahhhh probabily you must code an empty RowDeleting event, sometimes it happens to me with custom column sorting (it requires an empty Sorting event). Added in my answer above

Comment: I tried with blank onRowDeleting method and I have no errors now but its just doing nothing :( This is so difficult!

Comment: why do you need RowDataBound method??

Comment: It's an event called by design when you delete a row in a GridView, see [https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting(v=vs.110).aspx] this link for details

Comment: Thanks:) but I meant the method you have in the answer: myGridView_RowDataBound.. I only have RowCommand and onRowDeleting.. I am trying to follow exactly you code

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your comment: RowDataBound is executed while the GridView is built and I use it to define the CommandName and CommandArgument for the imageButton (parameters passed to RowCommand event when you click on the imageButton). I think it makes code clearer than your Cast(.. Cast(....  just a personal opinion ;)

Comment: Oh I see. Many Thanks. still trying to get it work! :D

Comment: My understanding from this link: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1497233   Is that I somehow need to rebind the gridview. does the above code work for you withough rebinding ?

Comment: Thank you so so so so MUCH! it finally worked, I had few names wrong!! :D